# Knockout table row access

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

First off, forgive the hard coded table data. I am doing a simple add row type of thing. I'm wondering how to get at the data in the sibling TDs. Should I be using a form? Or something else? basically I just need access to the data that is already in there and move it to another table.

```
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Resources">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: type">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: contact">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: status">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" data-bind="click: addResourceToList" value="Add Resource" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here is the start of the code in the model.

```
    addResourceToList = function () {
        self.ResourcesInPlan.push(new ResourceListModel({ name: this.title }));
    };
```

Thanks for any advice.

**Update**: The data was there, but I missed it. I changed to this line.

```
  self.ResourcesInPlan.push(new ResourceListModel(this.name));
```

Because I was referencing the model wrong as you can see.

Comment: your viewModel should have all the data you need, since you are adding to it.  But i'm unsure that I understand your question fully.

Comment: When I push that item into the resourcesinplan, it is undefined, I guess I'm not sure how to populate it properly, might be halfway there. But this results in Name = [object Object]. I'm not super great at js in general so maybe I'm doing something really basic/wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_1_passing_a_current_item_as_a_parameter_to_your_handler_function

KO will send the item as the first parameter to the function too.